# python, tkinter: how all variables can be obtained by single button from all notebook tabs?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to return all variables from all tabs by clicking on ok button. 
I have two tabs. What I want is that when I enter some value in 2nd tab, it should automatically appear in first tab in 'height' entry.
Then if I click 'ok' in first tab, it should return all  variables(from first tab and 2nd tab) to my 'main' program for further use.
Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App1(ttk.Frame):
    def createWidgets(self):
        #text variables
        self.i_height = StringVar()
        self.i_weight = StringVar()
        self.o_bmi = StringVar()

        #labels
        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self, text="Enter your weight:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="Enter your height:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.label3 = ttk.Label(self, text="Your BMI is:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

        #text boxes
        self.textbox1 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.i_weight).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)
        self.textbox2 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.i_height).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)
        self.textbox3 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.o_bmi).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)

        #buttons
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Cancel/Quit", command=self.quit).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Ok", command=self.calculateBmi).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=E)

    def calculateBmi(self):
        try:
            self.weight = float(self.i_weight.get())
            self.height = float(self.i_height.get())
            self.bmi = self.weight / self.height ** 2.0
            self.o_bmi.set(self.bmi)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "You can only use numbers.")
        finally:
            self.i_weight.set("")
            self.i_height.set("")

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

class App2(ttk.Frame):
    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create the widgets for the GUI"""
        #1 textbox (stringvar)
        self.entry= StringVar()
        self.textBox1= ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry).grid(row=0, column=1)

        #5 labels (3 static, 1 stringvar)
        self.displayLabel1 = ttk.Label(self, text="feet").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.displayLabel2 = ttk.Label(self, text="is equivalent to:").grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.result= StringVar()
        self.displayLabel3 = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.result).grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.displayLabel4 = ttk.Label(self, text="meters").grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)

        #2 buttons
        self.quitButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(S,E))
        self.calculateButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Calculate", command=self.convert_feet_to_meters).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=(S,E))

    def convert_feet_to_meters(self):
        """Converts feet to meters, uses string vars and converts them to floats"""
        self.measurement = float(self.entry.get())
        self.meters = self.measurement * 0.3048
        self.result.set(self.meters)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

def button1_click():
    root = Tk()
    app = App1(master=root)
    app.mainloop()

def button2_click():
    root = Tk()
    app = App2(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
def main():
    #Setup Tk()
    window = Tk()

    #Setup the notebook (tabs)
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(window)
    frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(frame1, text="BMI Calc")
    notebook.add(frame2, text="Feet to Meters")
    notebook.grid()

    #Create tab frames
    app1 = App1(master=frame1)
    app1.grid()
    app2 = App2(master=frame2)
    app2.grid()

    #Main loop
    window.mainloop()
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some fundamental mistakes in your program -- you cannot have three mainloops running at the same. You should always only have exactly one instance of Tk, and call mainloop exactly once.

Regardless of that, the solution is that you need to create a method or public variable in the app, and then your button callback needs to be able to call that method or access that variable.

For example, you would do it like this:

```
def callback():
    value1 = app1.getValue()
    value2 = app2.getValue()
    ...
```